# Relay Framework uncaught TypeError: this.props.relay.commitUpdate is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I am learning Relay framework and GraphQL. I am following the [tutorial from its official website.](https://web.archive.org/web/20171115114905/http://facebook.github.io:80/relay/docs/tutorial.html) In that tutorial, I would build a game using GraphQL mutations. The goal of the game is to find a hidden treasure in a grid of 9 squares. Everything was fine when I run it on the server, but when I did a click action to one of the grid, the app threw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.relay.commitUpdate is not a function
```

From the console's log, I could clearly see that there is no `commitUpdate()` function in `this.props.relay`, but I got confused since in the [Relay's playground](https://web.archive.org/web/20170619085821/http://facebook.github.io:80/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=/**), I could see that there is a `commitUpdate()` function in `this.props.relay`.

Any thoughts?

%20*%20Copyright%20(c)%202013-present,%20Facebook,%20Inc.
%20*%20All%20rights%20reserved.
%20*
%20*%20This%20source%20code%20is%20licensed%20under%20the%20BSD-style%20license%20found%20in%20the
%20*%20LICENSE%20file%20in%20the%20root%20directory%20of%20this%20source%20tree.%20An%20additional%20grant
%20*%20of%20patent%20rights%20can%20be%20found%20in%20the%20PATENTS%20file%20in%20the%20same%20directory.
%20*/

//%20Welcome%20to%20Relay.
//%20Allow%20us%20to%20introduce%20you%20to%20the%20four%20elements.

/**
%20*%20#1%20-%20Your%20React%20components
%20*%20This%20will%20look%20familiar%20to%20React%20developers.
%20*
%20*%20To%20learn%20more%20about%20React,%20visit:
%20*%20%20https://facebook.github.io/react
%20*/
class%20HelloApp%20extends%20React.Component%20{
%20%20_handleClick(){
%20%20%20%20console.log(this.props.relay);
%20%20}
%20%20renderMain(){
%20%20%20%20const%20{goodbye}%20=%20this.props.greetings;
%20%20%20%20return%20<h1%20onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>{goodbye}
%20%20}
%20%20render()%20{
%20%20%20%20//%20Relay%20will%20materialize%20this%20prop%20based%20on%20the
%20%20%20%20//%20result%20of%20the%20query%20in%20the%20next%20component.
%20%20%20%20console.log(this.props.greetings);
%20%20%20%20const%20{hello}%20=%20this.props.greetings;
%20%20%20%20return%20<h1%20onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>{hello}{this.renderMain()};
%20%20}
}

/**
%20*%20#2%20-%20Relay%20containers
%20*%20Compose%20your%20React%20components%20with%20a%20declaration%20of
%20*%20the%20GraphQL%20query%20fragments%20that%20fetch%20their%20data.
%20*
%20*%20To%20learn%20more%20about%20Relay%20containers,%20visit:
%20*%20%20%20https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-containers.html
%20*/
HelloApp%20=%20Relay.createContainer(HelloApp,%20{
%20%20fragments:%20{
%20%20%20%20//%20This%20GraphQL%20query%20executes%20against
%20%20%20%20//%20the%20schema%20in%20the%20'schema'%20tab%20above.
%20%20%20%20//
%20%20%20%20//%20To%20learn%20more%20about%20Relay.QL,%20visit:
%20%20%20%20//%20%20%20https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-ql.html
%20%20%20%20greetings:%20()%20=>%20Relay.QL `%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Greetings%20{ %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hello, %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20goodbye, %20%20%20%20%20%20} %20%20%20%20`,
%20%20}
});

/**
%20*%20#3%20-%20Relay%20routes
%20*%20Define%20a%20root%20GraphQL%20query%20into%20which%20your
%20*%20containers'%20query%20fragments%20will%20be%20composed.
%20*
%20*%20To%20learn%20more%20about%20Relay%20routes,%20visit:
%20*%20%20%20https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-routes.html
%20*/
class%20HelloRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20{
%20%20static%20routeName%20=%20'Hello';%20%20//%20A%20unique%20name
%20%20static%20queries%20=%20{
%20%20%20%20//%20Here,%20we%20compose%20your%20Relay%20container's
%20%20%20%20//%20'greetings'%20fragment%20into%20the%20'greetings'
%20%20%20%20//%20field%20at%20the%20root%20of%20the%20GraphQL%20schema.
%20%20%20%20greetings:%20(Component)%20=>%20Relay.QL `%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20GreetingsQuery%20{ %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greetings%20{ %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20${Component.getFragment('greetings')}, %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20}, %20%20%20%20%20%20} %20%20%20%20`,
%20%20};
}

/**
%20*%20#4%20-%20Relay%20root%20containers
%20*%20Compose%20a%20Relay%20container%20with%20a%20Relay%20route.
%20*%20This%20enables%20Relay%20to%20synthesize%20a%20complete%20query
%20*%20to%20fetch%20the%20data%20necessary%20to%20render%20your%20app.
%20*
%20*%20To%20learn%20more%20about%20Relay%20root%20containers,%20visit:
%20*%20%20%20https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-root-container.html
%20*/
ReactDOM.render(
%20%20<Relay.RootContainer
%20%20%20%20Component={HelloApp}
%20%20%20%20route={new%20HelloRoute()}
%20%20/>,
%20%20mountNode
);
&schema=/**
%20*%20Copyright%20(c)%202013-present,%20Facebook,%20Inc.
%20*%20All%20rights%20reserved.
%20*
%20*%20This%20source%20code%20is%20licensed%20under%20the%20BSD-style%20license%20found%20in%20the
%20*%20LICENSE%20file%20in%20the%20root%20directory%20of%20this%20source%20tree.%20An%20additional%20grant
%20*%20of%20patent%20rights%20can%20be%20found%20in%20the%20PATENTS%20file%20in%20the%20same%20directory.
%20*/

import%20{
%20%20GraphQLObjectType,
%20%20GraphQLSchema,
%20%20GraphQLString,
}%20from%20'graphql';

const%20GREETINGS%20=%20{
%20%20hello:%20'Hello',
%20%20goodbye:%20'Goodbye'
};

/**
%20*%20Objects.
%20*%20Build%20up%20a%20portrait%20of%20your%20data%20universe
%20*%20using%20the%20object%20type.%20Here,%20we%20define%20a
%20*%20type%20of%20object%20that%20has%20a%20'hello'%20field
%20*%20that%20is%20of%20the%20string%20type.
%20*/
const%20GreetingsType%20=%20new%20GraphQLObjectType({
%20%20name:%20'Greetings',
%20%20fields:%20()%20=>%20({
%20%20%20%20hello:%20{type:%20GraphQLString},
%20%20%20%20goodbye:%20{type:%20GraphQLString}
%20%20}),
});

/**
%20*%20The%20schema.
%20*%20Here%20we%20export%20a%20schema%20that%20offers%20one%20root
%20*%20field%20named%20'greetings',%20and%20a%20method%20to
%20*%20resolve%20its%20data.
%20*
%20*%20To%20learn%20more%20about%20writing%20GraphQL%20schemas%20for%20Relay,%20visit:
%20*%20%20%20https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js
%20*/
export%20default%20new%20GraphQLSchema({
%20%20query:%20new%20GraphQLObjectType({
%20%20%20%20name:%20'Query',
%20%20%20%20fields:%20()%20=>%20({
%20%20%20%20%20%20greetings:%20{
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type:%20GreetingsType,
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Here%20we%20define%20a%20resolver%20that%20returns
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20the%20data%20defined%20above.%20Were%20this%20schema
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20executing%20on%20the%20server%20side,%20you%20could
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20write%20a%20resolve%20method%20that%20fetches
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20live%20data%20from%20a%20database.
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve:%20()%20=>%20GREETINGS,
%20%20%20%20%20%20},
%20%20%20%20}),
%20%20}),
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@asubanovsky The [Relay Starter Kit](https://github.com/CoericK/relay-starter-kit) seems to be outdated compared with the [Relay Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20171115114905/http://facebook.github.io:80/relay/docs/tutorial.html#writing-the-game), so a better solution would be to update your version of 'react-relay' from 0.8.1 to 0.9.0 and then `npm install`, undo the change that u made to `Relay.Store.commitUpdate` and you will be ready to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After observing for few hours, I finally managed to solve the problem. I don't know whether this is a good solution or not. I changed `this.props.relay.commitUpdate` with `Relay.Store.commitUpdate`. The app then works as expected.

Comment: Turn out, I used an old version of react-relay. I followed Erick Arroyo's answer and everything worked as expected.